# How to preselected checkbox show when again arraylist open in android

Tags: java, android

First I am selecting some array item using *checkbox* and displaying it in second activity. After that I am again opening my first activity of `ArrayList` but my checkbox selection clears.

Below is my code

```
public class Occassion extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView listView_occassion;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterOccassion;
Button mButtonOccassionNext;
int position;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_occassion);

    listView_occassion = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.occassion_listview);
    mButtonOccassionNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_occassion_next);

    listView_occassion.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    String[] Occassion = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.occassion_array);

    adapterOccassion = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, Occassion);


    listView_occassion.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView_occassion.setAdapter(adapterOccassion);
    mButtonOccassionNext.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Filters.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    SparseBooleanArray checked = listView_occassion.getCheckedItemPositions();

    ArrayList<String> selectedItemsOccassion = new ArrayList<String>();
    Utils.occassionArrayList.clear();

    for (i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
        // Item position in adapter
        int position = checked.keyAt(i);
        // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
        if (checked.valueAt(i))
            // selectedItemsFlavour.add(adapterFlavour.getItem(position));
            Utils.occassionArrayList.add(adapterOccassion.getItem(position));
    }

}
```

}

Display second activity as result..

```
mtv_occassion_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_occassion_status);

if(!Utils.occassionArrayList.isEmpty()){
        String tempOccassion= String.valueOf(Utils.occassionArrayList);
        mtv_occassion_status.setText(tempOccassion);
    }
```

And my array list add in String.xml

```
<string-array name="occassion_array">
    <item>Birthday</item>
    <item>Wedding</item>
    <item>Anniversary</item>
    <item>Celebration</item>
    <item>Get Well Soon</item>
    <item>House warming</item>
    <item>Valentines Day</item>
    <item>Diwali</item>
    <item>Friendship Day</item>
    <item>X-Mas</item>
    <item>New Year</item>
    <item>Random</item>
</string-array>
```

Any help would be great for me.

Answer (score 2):

create a class like:

```
class Occasion {
public String name;
public boolean status;
}
```

after that create a arraylist:

```
ArrayList<Occasion> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and put your items with selection status into this arraylist like this:

```
String[] occassion = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.occassion_array);

for(int i=0; i < occassion.lenght(); i++){

   String name = occasion[i];
   Occasion obj = new Occasion();
   obj.name = name;
   obj.status = getItemStatus(name);
   datalist.add(obj);

}
```

now pass this datalist to your adapter and set the check status on the basis of status parameter of **Occasion class**

```
private boolean getItemStatus(String name) {

String items = getSharedPreferences("pref", 0).getString("items", "");
if(items.contains(name){
    return true;
}
return false;

}
```

and

```
@Override
```

public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

```
    String selectedItemName = dataList.get(i).name;
String items = getSharedPreferences("pref", 0).getString("items", "");

if(!dataList.get(i).status) {

    if(items.equals("")) {

        items = selectedItemName;

    } else {

        items = items +","+ selectedItemName;

    }

} else {

    items = items.replace(selectedItemName, "");

}

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("pref", 0).edit();
editor.putString("items", items);
    editor.apply();

dataList.get(i).status = !dataList.get(i).status;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

now you have to change your adapter class only. In that class under **getView()** you have to check the status of each item and select the checkbox accordingly.

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Sir.. am executing your answer but when am again go to my arraylist it black no checkbox is selected. Means when am select Birthday and wedding checkbox my textview give right result and again am going my listarray it will be blank not selected birthday and wdding

Comment: Hey I have edited my answer, please go through this.

Answer (score 1):

Check this .

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<adapterOccassion.size ;i++)
{
if(Utils.occassionArrayList.contains(adapterOccassion.getItem(i)))
   {
       // set checked 
   }
}
```

Comment: For that create array list . and add item in list when user check checkbox .

Comment: yes am createing my arraylist "Utils.occassionArrayList" and my selected item also add and display result in next activity textview. But when am again open my arraylist it not selected privous checkbox selected item.